# Can't set a bash variable using exec command in Puppet

Tags: linux, bash, variables, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I'm trying to set the result of a bash command in a variable using the exec command in Puppet :

```
 exec { 'test':
     command => "test=$(pwd)",
     path =>  [ '/bin/', '/sbin/' , '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/' ],
     logoutput => true,
}
```

But it's giving me a :

`Error: Could not find command 'test=$(pwd)'`

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: include `provider => 'shell',`

Comment: This works! Although I'm trying to print the result by using 

`echo ${test}` 

and its saying that test is an unknown variable. 

What would be the correct way to access the contents of the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to set the result of a bash command in a variable using the exec command in Puppet :
>
> ```
> exec { 'test':
>      command => "test=$(pwd)",
>      path =>  [ '/bin/', '/sbin/' , '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/' ],
>      logoutput => true,
> }
> ```

On Linux, the default provider for `Exec` resources is `posix`.  If you want the command to be executed via a shell then you need to ask for that by adding

```
     provider => 'shell',
```

But you cannot affect Puppet's execution environment from within such a shell, so any environment variables you set, shell options you modify, *etc* will be in effect only for the duration of that command.  For example, you cannot that way set environment variables for a subsequent `Exec` to use.

That is, this will work as expected:

```
# Ok

exec { 'test':
  command   => 'test=$(pwd); echo "${test}"',
  path      => ['/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
  logoutput => true,
  provider  => 'shell',
}
```

, but this is unlikely to produce the same result:

```
# Not what you want!

exec { 'set test':
  command   => 'test=$(pwd)',
  path      => ['/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
  logoutput => true,
  provider  => 'shell',
}

exec { 'print test':
  command   => 'echo "${test}"',
  path      => ['/bin', '/sbin' , '/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
  logoutput => true,
  provider  => 'shell',
}
```

(Note also quoting.  Puppet will expand `${test}` where it appears in a double-quoted string, possibly to nothing.  To avoid that, escape the `$` as `\$` or use single quotes instead of double quotes.)

---

It's unclear what your overall objective is, because `pwd` is not a useful thing to be capturing in an `Exec` resource.  If you care about the locations of files, then you should be referring to them via absolute paths, except inasmuch as you may use simple command names that can be resolved against the path you specify in your `Exec`.

If you want to add variables to your commands' (quite sparse) environments then the `environment` parameter of the `Exec` resource is usually the most appropriate way to do it, but you cannot use command substitutions there.  You *can*, however, interpolate the values of facts or ordinary Puppet variables, and that might be a good route to what you're after.

If you want to execute a complex-ish series of related shell commands, then you could consider writing a shell script to a file on the target system, and executing that.  Or look for an existing module that does what you want, or even write a custom resource type that uses Ruby (and maybe shell commands underneath) to do it.